# Sending e-mail from html webpage without using outlook

Tags: html, email

Can i have any plugin or some script to send email from html webpage?

I dont want email to be sent using outlook configuration or something.

I need to send email from Contact Me page of my website.
Rest whole website is static i dnt want to use server just for contact me webpage

So i cant use the following code

```
<p>
This is an email link:
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">
Send Mail</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I browser cannot send an email from a page. A browser can send a message to a server which can, in turn, send an email on your behalf.

What you're doing right now is valid, but only if you want the email to be opened in the clients respective email program, which it sounds like you don't.

So the short answer is, no, this isn't possible.

Comment: So how do you recommend me to make my webpage? when i host my website how will i host on server..eg tomcat?

Comment: I'm afraid this is beyond the scope of this question. Best thing to do would be to accept this answer and ask another question specifically about the best hosting solutions.